# Select key and one value out of tuples with multiple values per key to create new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I started recently learning programming Python and I am running into a problem. I tried to solve this myself, unsuccessfully.

I have a dictionary with a formatted string as a key and tuples with 3 values per key.

`dict1 = { “a;2;1;1;” : ( 1, 2, 3), “a;3;2;1;” : ( 4, 5, 6)}`

I want to create a new dictionary dict2 with all keys from dict1 and only the third value from each key.

`dict2 = { “a;2;1;1;” : 3, “a;3;2;1;” : 6}`

In these examples I used only two key-value pairs, the real dictionary has ten thousand of key-value pairs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with a simple iteration:

```
dict2 = dict()
for k in dict1:
    dict2[k] = dict1[k][2]
```

Or use a dict-comprehension to do it in a single line:

```
dict2 = {k: dict1[k][2] for k in dict1}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 Line solution, could probably be done in a more 'python' way but this will work:

```
dict1 = {'a;2;1;1;' : ( 1, 2, 3), 'a;3;2;1;' : ( 4, 5, 6)}
dict2 = {}

# You just need these two lines here
for k in dict1:
    dict2[k] = dict1[k][2]

print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = { 'a;2;1;1;' : ( 1, 2, 3), 'a;3;2;1;' : ( 4, 5, 6)}
dict2 = {}

for k in dict1.keys():
    dict2[k] = dict1[k][2]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a dictionary comprehension also:

```py
dict1 = { “a;2;1;1;” : ( 1, 2, 3), “a;3;2;1;” : ( 4, 5, 6)}
dict2 = {x: y for (x,(_,_,y)) in dict1.items()}
```